# Get network interface IPv4 address in a netfilter hook

Tags: networking, kernel, network-interface, netfilter

To my understanding the

```
const struct net_device *in
```

hook parameter describes the network interface that the packet came in through.

Is there any possible way to get the IPv4 address of the interface from that struct?

kernel version 3.2.0

thanks

Comment: You mean the IPv4 address**es** if any?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ok I think I've managed to get the IP with the following line: 

`((in->ip_ptr)->ifa_list)->ifa_address`

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the code I needed [here](https://lists.openwall.net/netdev/2007/11/20/131).
My adapters only have one IPv4 address so I managed getting it with:

```
((in->ip_ptr)->ifa_list)->ifa_address;
```